# Solve the initial value problem for the ODE

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations, derivatives

$\biggl\{y′′(t)−6y′(t) + 9y(t) = 18 $

$y(0) = 2, \quad y′(0) = 1$

First I found the general solution to $y′′(t)−6y′(t) + 9y(t) = 18$
which I got to be $y(t)=(A+Bt)$$e^{3t}+2$

but how do I use $y(0)$ and $y'(0)$ to find A and B?

Comment: **Hint:** You should find the particular solution first and then use the ICs. After you find $y = y_h + y_p$, then using your $y(t)$, find $y'(t)$ and then use **each IC** to create an equation in $A$ and $B$ and then solve that $2~x~2$.

Comment: your solution is incomplete

Comment: @ZachBoyd It should be 2, sorry

Comment: @Moo Thank you very much!

Comment: You are welcome, what did you conclude for $A$ and $B$?

Comment: @Moo $A=0$ and $B=1$ :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Start to finish:
The equation $y′′(t)−6y′(t) + 9y(t) = 18$ can be seen to have a solution of the form $y(t) = f(t) + 2$ leading to $f'' - 6 f' + 9f=0$. With a solution of the form $f = e^{a t}$ the differential equation becomes an algebraic equation of the form $a^{2} - 6 a + 9 = (a-3)^2 = 0$. Since this is an equal root equation then $f$ takes the form $f(t) = (c_{0} + c_{1} \, t) \, e^{3 \, t}$ and finally
$$y(t) = 2 + (c_{0} + c_{1} \, t) \, e^{3 \, t}.$$

Now to apply the conditions: $y(0) = 2$, and $y′(0) = 1$.

Since $y'(t) = [(3 c_{0} + c_{1}) + c_{1} \, t] \, e^{3 \, t}$ then
\begin{align}
y(0) = 2 &= 2 + c_{0} \\
y'(0) = 1 &= 3 c_{0} + c_{1}
\end{align}
which yields the solutions $c_{0} = 0$ and $c_{1} = 1$ and the general solution
$$y(t) = 2 + t \, e^{3 \, t}.$$